# Change query to use binding parameters and prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, pdo

I am running a php script with a query in it, and it loops through an echos some html that has information from the DB embedded in it. I am wondering how I could write this so that it uses prepared statements and bind_param()...

```
<?php
               mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
               error_reporting(E_ALL);
               ini_set("display_errors", 1);
               // error reporting is now turned on

               require_once 'dbconfig.php';

               try {
                   $mysqli= new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname); 
                   if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                       die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                           . $mysqli->connect_error);
                    }
                }
                catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
                    throw $e; 
                } 

                if($_POST['food'] == "No") {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE food LIKE '%Yes%' OR food LIKE '%No%'";
                }
                else {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE food LIKE '%Yes%'";
                }

                $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if($row["name"] != "name" && $row["description"] != "description") {
                       echo
                       "<div class='col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4'>
                           <div class='thumbnail'>
                               <img src='images/mug-icon.png' alt=''>
                               <div class='caption'>
                                   <h4><a href='#'>" . $row["name"] . "</a>
                                   </h4>
                                   <p>" . substr($row["description"],0, 175) . "...</p>
                               </div>
                               <div class='ratings'>
                                   <p>
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>
                                   </p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>";
                     }
                }
                $mysqli->close();
               ?>
```

Comment: You could start by reading [the documentation on this subject](http://php.net/pdo) and try what you learn from it.

Comment: @Oldskool Sorry I can update the post, I have tried for hours to do this, and researched much of the documentation but was unsuccessful. I used the php manual, as well as w3c. I continued to get errors such a the bind_param() method was not defined, I scoured the stack for other posts but was also unsuccessful. My code looked identical to the instructions but I continued to get errors.

Comment: @Oldskool : bind_param belongs to mysqli, not pdo

Comment: I will try this thank you

Comment: @VolkerK Good point, I was confusing it with PDO's `bindParam()` method.

Comment: btw: what parameters do you want to bind to a statement? Right now I don't see much potential for that. In the script you've posted there are two two sql statements which both are not in immediate need of being replaced by prepared statement+parameter(s).

Comment: @VolkerK I'm in the process of building the statements. There are 5 drop down menus in a single form, each drop down has 5 possible values

Comment: Then show us code where there are parameters you can bind and ask a concrete question ;-) Right now you have fixed string literals in your LIKE clause and that's ok, no urgent need for parameters there.